# How do I hide expander in Hierarchical Data Template when all children are collapsed or hidden?

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I Have a tree view set up like so:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding TreeRoot}" x:Name="HierarchyTreeView">
    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}>
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding IsVisible, Converter={...}}" />
            ...
        </Style>
    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>

    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" ... />
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

Users have the ability to hide items in the treeview. However, when all items' visibility under a node has been set to `Collapsed` or `Hidden`, the expander remains.

**Is there any way to hide the expander when every child's visibility under an item is set to hidden or collapsed?**

Comment: You can set the visibility on the Expandar but then how would the users expand it.

Comment: They wouldn't expand it. If none of the children are visible, expanding would serve no purpose. An expander with no children might also make a user believe that the program is malfunctioning in some way when they expand an item only to see there are no children.

Comment: Set the visibility on the Expandar to collapsed.  So once they collapse they can never go back?   A user will never collapse a TreeView and then want to come back and see children.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was facing this issue and came across this question. I saw there were some answers where you needed to make this change in the TreeViewItem style which required you to edit the default style.
However, like the case above I too just needed the expander to be not visible when the node items are hidden.
A simple way to do it is to expand all your nodes by default and use a property in the datatrigger for the TreeViewItem style to set the TreeViewItem visibility.
This is how I was able to achieve it.

```
<Style x:Key="myTreeItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
  <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True"/>     
  <Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsVisible}" Value="True">
      <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
    </DataTrigger>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsVisible}" Value="False">
      <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
    </DataTrigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Now, use this style as the TreeView ItemContainerStyle:

```
<TreeView Name="treeView" ItemsSource="{Binding TreeItems}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource myTreeItemStyle}" BorderThickness="0"/>
```